# About a reference collecting the main properties of the modulus and the argument of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, analyticity

Let $f$ be an analytic function in the whole complex plane. We can write $f$ in its polar form: $$f(z)=ρ(z)exp(iθ(z))$$
My **question** is about a reference collecting the main properties of the modulus and the argument of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not clear how to write $f$ is polar form globally. The function $\theta$ is undefined at the zeros of $f$, and does not have a single-values continuous branch around them. The most basic properties of these functions are:

- $\rho$ is subharmonic on $\mathbb C$, and harmonic on $\mathbb C\setminus f^{-1}(0)$.
- $\theta$ is  harmonic on simply-connected subdomains of $\mathbb C\setminus f^{-1}(0)$.

As for references:

- *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* by Ransford covers the fundamental properties of harmonic and subharmonic functions, relating them to holomorphic functions.
- Any book on entire functions  considers the global behavior of $\rho$ in detail (sometimes, in excruciating detail). For example, [entire functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=MVk5jCQVuiYC) by R.P. Boas or  [Introduction to the theory of entire functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=uuwxMtZEgWwC) by A.S.B. Holland.
  For the devotees of the subject,  *Subharmonic functions Vol II* by  Hayman can be recommended, but this is definitely not a first reading.  I  think these books don't spend much time on $\theta$ because it's not a globally defined function.
- There is also *Harmonic function theory* (Axler, Bourdon, Wade) if you are specifically interested in harmonic functions.

As far as I know, nobody ever wrote a book to  "collect the main properties of the modulus and the argument"; generally speaking, this is not what mathematicians do.